# Store temporary 64 bit variable in a 32 bit machine

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I'm doing some programming on a 32bit machine. 
As part of an algorithm to calculate collisions between objects in 3d I have to get the results of a dot product:

```
    //Vector3 components are signed int
    signed long GaMhVecDotL(const Vector3 *p_a, const Vector3 *p_b)
    {
        return ((p_a->vx * p_b->vx + p_a->vy * p_b->vy + p_a->vz * p_b->vz));
    }
```

In some cases this result overflows the 32 bit returning value (`signed long`).
I have tried a couple of things:

1. Bitshift the Vector3 components before sending them to this function
   to reduce the size. This works in most cases but I lose precision and
   that makes the algorithm fail in some edge cases.
2. Storing the result of the operation in a `long long` variable,
   and although it compiles it doesn't seem to store the variables
   correctly (this is for some PSX homebrew, compiler and tools haven't been updated since the late 90s).

I actually don't need to know the full result of the Dot Product, **I would just need to know if the result is positive, negative or 0 and at the same time trying to preserve as much precision as possible.**

Is there any way I can store the result of that operation (`p_a->vx * p_b->vx + p_a->vy * p_b->vy + p_a->vz * p_b->vz`) in a temp 64 bit var (or 2x32 bit) that would allow me later to check if this var is positive, negative or 0?

Comment: "*I have tried a couple of things*" - then please show the actual code you've tried, not just a vague description of what you think you've tried. We can't debug a paraphrase.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way I can store the result of that operation `(p_a->vx * p_b->vx + p_a->vy * p_b->vy + p_a->vz * p_b->vz)` in a temp 64 bit var (or 2x32 bit) that would allow me later to check if this var is positive, negative or 0?

This uses 32-bit math, (given int is 32-bit). Storing the return in a 64-bit result does not make the equation 64-bit.

```
// 32-bit math
p_a->vx * p_b->vx + p_a->vy * p_b->vy + p_a->vz * p_b->vz
```

Instead, use 64 bit math in the equation.

```
//               v-----------------v multiplication now done as 64-bit
long long dot = (1LL*p_a->vx*p_b->vx) + (1LL*p_a->vy*p_b->vy) + (1LL*p_a->vz*p_b->vz);
```

Then check sign-ness

```
if (dot < 0) return -1;
return dot > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks so much chux for providing an answer! Unfortunately using "long long" variables doesn't seem to work on the platform (Play Station 1). Let's you compile but the results are all over the place. As far as I know the PSX compiler is a custom version of gcc from the 90s, it seems under the hood is not handling well this temp 64 variables :(

Comment: @Walrfi How did you determine the "results are all over the place"?

Comment: For example the results of A(1248, 0, 46080) * B(-2541, -137, 1011) gives me -1 but it should be +1 (43415712)

Comment: @Walrfi Are your `int` 32 or 16 bit?  What is needed is a _code_ example.

Comment: "compiler and tools haven't been updated since the late 90s", so it is possible that the multiplication with `1LL` got optimized away while ignoring the implicit cast or the implicit cast got ignored or is implemented in a wrong way. I would try it with explicit casts everywhere (`(long long)(p_a->vx)*(long long)(p_b->vx)+...`) instead.

Comment: @Walrfi Check the type of Vector3's members. Might be int16_t and `A(1248, 0, 46080)` produces a negative z.